# How do partial updates happen in practice?

Tags: sql, rdbms

I learned about normalization and, in particular, that several kinds of anomalies may happen if there are redundancies in the table. Let me focus on the modification anomaly. Suppose a table with the columns `Student_id`, `Department_id`, `Department_head`. So, if the CS department gets a new department head and this information is updated only for some of the rows concerned with the CS department, then an inconsistency will result. I am trying to understand two things:

- How can such a partial update happen in practice when we use the `UPDATE` query?
- How is partial update worse than the update not happening at all? Can't we simply re-run the query in both cases?

Comment: Did u researched about SCD's in SSIS or merge procedures in SQL ?

Comment: Normalize the data and this won't happen.  You should have a separate table, say `Departments`, and the department head should only be in that table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The question states clearly that I know about normalization. I am asking *how* bad things can happen in practice *without* normalization.